# What does "Drop Connections" and "Update Statistics" in the "Detach Database" dialog do?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

As a testing phase I have installed the evaluation version of SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition.

When I detach a database through SQL Server Management Studio, I see two options:

1. Drop Connections
2. Update Statistics

[image]

Both options will detach the database from the SQL Server Instance.  What is the difference between the two options?

Comment: Why are you detaching databases, never mind using the UI? Please see http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supplementing to the current answer...

Detach database will leave you without any backup. If for some reason, you cannot attach database, you will end up with a detached copy of mdf and ldf.

A best practice should be to do a backup and restore of the database. This way you end up with at least a copy of the database.

Read up : http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/

Answer (score 11):

`Drop Connections` will force the database into Single User mode before detaching the database, thereby forcing all users to disconnect.  If you don't check-mark that option, and users are connected to the database, the database will not be detached.

`Update Statistics` will refresh any out of date statistics before detaching the database.  If you leave this option un-checked, statistics objects will remain as they were at the time you detached the database.

Microsoft has an excellent article with more details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191491.aspx).